# join 2 tables and sort using max value of one of them

Tags: mysql

I have talks table, and talk_items table.

Talk has a is_performed, created_at and family_id fields.
Talk_item has created_at field.

(both have more fields but they can be ignored for the question)

A talk can have talk_items and can have **none**.

I need to sort talks first by the is_performed field (talks that were not performed should be first) and then by the latest date of a talk_item if there is, and if there isn't, by the creation date of the talk itself.

I have this query:

```
SELECT talks.*, 
       IFNULL(talk_items.created_at, talks.created_at) AS 
       sorting_date 
FROM   `talks` 
       LEFT JOIN talk_items 
              ON talk_items.talk_id = talks.id 
WHERE  talks.family_id = 35536 

ORDER  BY talks.is_performed ASC, 
          sorting_date DESC
```

But this query gives me multiple talks if a talk has more than one talk_item.

How can I get the **DISTINCT** talk and the date of the most recent talk_item of that talk (the id of the talk_item can be used for that)?

Database id MYSQL.

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't adding a

```
group by talks.id
```

solve this?

Otherwise something like this:

```
SELECT talks.*, 
       IFNULL(talk_items.created_at, talks.created_at) AS 
       sorting_date 
FROM   `talks` 
       LEFT JOIN 
              (SELECT * FROM talk_items group by talk_id) as items
        ON items.talk_id = talks.id 
WHERE  talks.family_id = 35536 

ORDER  BY talks.is_performed ASC, 
          sorting_date DESC
```